# System.InvalidOperationException: "Fill: Свойство SelectCommand.Connection не инициализировано."

Tags: c#, sql, .net

```cs
        public partial class Database : Form
        {
            MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();
            BindingSource source = new BindingSource();
            MySqlConnectionStringBuilder str = new MySqlConnectionStringBuilder
            {
                Server = "***********",
                Port = *****,
                Database = "*****************",
                UserID = "********************",
                Password = "***************",
                CharacterSet = "utf8"
            };
            MySqlConnection connection;
            string current;
    
            public Database()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }
          private void Databese_Load(Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
            {
                connection = new MySqlConnection(str.ConnectionString);
                connection.Open();
            }
            private void Gett(string str)
            {
                current = str;
                str = "`****************`." + str + ";";
                str = "SELECT * FROM " + str;
                adapter.SelectCommand = new MySqlCommand(str, connection);
                
                DataTable dataSet = new DataTable();
                adapter.Fill(dataSet); //тут ошибка  
                adapter.UpdateCommand = new MySqlCommandBuilder(adapter).GetUpdateCommand();
                source.DataSource = dataSet;
                Data.DataSource = source;
            }
        }
```

При попытке вывести в Datagrid

> System.InvalidOperationException: "Fill: Свойство
> SelectCommand.Connection не инициализировано."

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Вы уверены, что `Databese_Load` выполняется? Оно подписано на `Form.Load`? Откуда вызывается метод, в котором ошибка?

Comment: adapter.Fill(dataSet) В данном методе ошибка

Comment: это понятно, что в `adapter.Fill(dataSet)` ошибка, где вызывается функция `Gett`?

Comment: private void ClientGroupsBt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
        {
            Gett("ClientGroups");
        }

Comment: Вы не ответили про обработчик `Load`

Comment: Я дико извиняюсь, но я не совсем понимаю о чём вы

Comment: `Databese_Load` метод видите? У вас он назначен обработчиком события `Form.Load`, или вы верите в магию, что оно само как-то должно работать? Зайдите в дизайнер формы, выберите саму форму, справа в углу нажмите на кнопку с молнией, выберите событие Load и выберите ему ваш обработчик.

Comment: Там вроде как всё верно потому что когда меняешь обработчик форма перестаёт открываться, суть в том что открывается форма с DataGridViev и данным методом я хочу вывести таблицу из бд, но когда прожимаешь кнопку ты выскакивает данная ошибка, дико извиняюсь за свою недалёкость просто относительно не давно начал изучать данный язык.